# How to post raw data as a parameters in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

How to post this form of parameters in Alamofire ?

```
[{"view_id":"108","Class_id":"VIII"}]
```

As normally `Alamofire` accept [`String:Any]` parameters and when I enter this parameter in `Alamofire` request then it raise an error :

```
"extra call method"
```

Answer (score 6):

You said `As normally Alamofire accept [String:Any] parameters` and then you are passing `[[String: Any]]`.

Try to pass your data in hhtpBody.

```
let urlString            = "yourString"
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
var request        = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
do {
    request.httpBody   = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: your_parameter_aaray)
} catch let error {
    print("Error : \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON{ (response) in
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom encoding to send the params in request. Check the [Alamofire docs on custom-encoding](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#custom-encoding)

```
struct JSONStringArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    private let jsonArray: [[String: String]]

    init(jsonArray: [[String: String]]) {
        self.jsonArray = jsonArray
    }

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()

        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonArray, options: [])

        if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
            urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        urlRequest.httpBody = data

        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

```
Alamofire.request("https://myserver.com/api/path", method: .post, encoding: JSONStringArrayEncoding).responseJSON { response in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Method To Solve:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).validate(statusCode: 200..<300) .responseJSON { response in
            

}
```